# How to count patches in same row with turtles on them?

Tags: row, patch, netlogo

I am trying to find a solution to do what `count neighbors with [any? turtles-here = true]' does, but instead of counting the black patches among the 8 neighboring patches to all patches that have the same y coordinate as the asking turtle.

Is there a way to implement a whole range of coordinates and ask for the number of patches with turtles within these coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do this!

`count patches with [ pycor = [ ycor ] of myself and any? turtles-here ]`

[`myself`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#myself) refers to the agent that is doing the asking of other agents. In this case, it refers to the turtle that's counting the patches. Here, the turtle is asking the patches to execute the code in the reporter block. In order to get the `ycor` of the turtle in the context of the reporter block, you do `[ ycor ] of myself`.

Also, as an aside, note that the `= true` is unnecessary. `any? turtles-here` is already returning `true` or `false`, which is what you want the reporter block to return anyway!